# Add div wrapper using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wrapper, appendchild, createelement

I am trying to create a [Twitters Bootstrap grid](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/) function using pure Javascript.

The problem is that the `column` is placed outside the `row`, but it should be inside.
Just like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
</div>
```

Right now my code posted below has this output

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="col-md-12"></div>
```

I tried to set the first inserted `div` as parent, but somehow when I use 
the `parentNode` property it returns always null.

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

This is my code so far

```
    var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    // Add row
    var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.className = 'row';
    docFrag.appendChild(row);

    // Add column
    var col = document.createElement('div');
        col.className = 'col-md-12';
    docFrag.appendChild(col);

    document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending it to the document fragment, not the row in the document fragment.

Change

```
docFrag.appendChild(col);
```

To

```
row.appendChild(col);
```

If you want it to be inside the row.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is much easier then I thought. Thanks for the solution!